# Верно ли стоит двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация, тире-или-двоеточие

А там уж я вам все в подробностях обскажу: и кто я, и откуда!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Налицо перечисление «подробностей», предваряемое двоеточием. Восклицание кажется сомнительным; обосновать его поможет знание контекста.